# Can scipy.signal function be called in MATLAB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, scipy

I have a python function that I need to call in MATLAB that imports functions from scipy.signal.

However when I attempt to call the function in MATLAB I get an error

```
Error using arpack><module> (line 45)
Python Error: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Error in __init__><module> (line 22)
from .arpack import *

Error in __init__><module> (line 11)
from .arpack import *

Error in __init__><module> (line 117)
from .eigen import *

Error in _minimize><module> (line 21)
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

Error in __init__><module> (line 271)
from ._minimize import *

Error in filter_design><module> (line 18)
from scipy import special, optimize, fftpack

Error in __init__><module> (line 321)
from .filter_design import *

Error in <frozen importlib>_call_with_frames_removed (line 219)

Error in <frozen importlib>exec_module (line 728)

Error in <frozen importlib>_load_unlocked (line 677)

Error in <frozen importlib>_find_and_load_unlocked (line 967)

Error in <frozen importlib>_find_and_load (line 983)

Error in <frozen importlib>_gcd_import (line 1006)

Error in __init__>import_module (line 127)
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
```

This occurs when both calling the python function from MATLAB or simply by typing

```
py.importlib.import_module('scipy.signal')
```

in the MATLAB command line. Attempting to call a scipy.signal function directly

```
py.scipy.signal.find_peaks()
```

throws the error

```
Undefined variable "py" or class "py.scipy.signal.find_peaks".
```

Importing (or calling) numpy, scipy, or numpy submodules on the other hand are all successful.

Is the scipy.signal submodule not able to be called in MATLAB, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call scipy.signal functions using this syntax e.g.
`myButterFilt = py.scipy.signal.butter(1,0.25)`

Comment: This throws the error `Undefined variable "py" or class "py.scipy.signal.butter"`. It seems to be an issue with scipy.signal specifically, since e.g. `py.scipy.array([0,0])` works

Comment: @strudel If you have scipy installed in a python environment other than the one MATLAB currently has loaded then you need to load a different python environment

Comment: I am definitely in the correct environment since MATLAB can load scipy/numpy/pandas etc. I ran MATLAB from the anaconda prompt to be sure but still scipy.signal throws the same errors.

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so try launching MATLAB from the command line with the script below. I changed my MATLAB shortcut Target to run this script instead of the normal startup because of python path problems. My python root lives in `%userprofile%\Miniconda` but you may have to adjust if yours is elsewhere. `%comspec% /c ""%userprofile%\Miniconda\Scripts\activate.bat" "%userprofile%\Miniconda" & """%MATLAB_ROOT%\bin\matlab.exe" -sd %userprofile%\Documents\MATLAB""`

Comment: Also I got the same error when I tried your command (`peak_finder`), but was able to run `find_peaks`. `>> py.scipy.signal.find_peaks(sin(2*pi*linspace(0,2,256)))
ans = 
  Python tuple with no properties.

    (array([ 32, 159], dtype=int64), {})`

Comment: yes oops I meant `find_peaks`. Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but no success. I can load other scipy submodules though e.g. `py.scipy.interpolate.interp1d()` which is what is most confusing to me. Which MATLAB version are you running? I'm on R2017a.

Comment: @strudel I am running MATLAB r2016b and I run a separate python 3.5 environment just for MATLAB : `conda create -v -y -n myenv35 python=3.5 numpy scipy scikit-learn sklearn-contrib-py-earth` The MATLAB python support for py3.6/7/8 has been problematic for me which is why I run the 3.5 sandbox, maybe worth a shot?

Comment: Good suggestion. Which scipy version are you running? I managed to get `py.scipy.signal.butter()` to work but not `py.scipy.signal.find_peaks()` on python 2.7 scipy 0.12. Neither work on python 3.5.

Comment: @strudel 
`(myenv35) C:\>pip list
Package                  Version
------------------------ ---------
certifi                  2018.8.24
matlabengineforpython    R2016b
mkl-fft                  1.0.9
mkl-random               1.0.1
numpy                    1.15.2
pip                      18.0
scikit-learn             0.20.0
scipy                    1.1.0
setuptools               40.4.3
six                      1.11.0
sklearn-contrib-py-earth 0.1.0
wheel                    0.32.0
wincertstore             0.2`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It seems to work with `python=3.5 scipy=1.1.0 numpy=1.15.2`, if nothing else!

Comment: @strudel, I am having the same problem when trying to import scipy.signal in matlab and also with other import which works for you but not for me (eg py.scipy.array([0,0])). I dont know Python at all but I have to call a python function written by other  so would you please guide me through this? Thank you very much